# xserver-xorg-core Crash

Tags: grub2, xorg, crash

I had the same (or very similar) problem some months ago, but after a while it disappeared. When existed I could use the system using upstart element of the Grub menu. After an October update of 16.04 it returned and produces the error report starting with

> **ExecuteablePath**
>        /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
>   **Package**
>        xserver-xorg-core 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.8
>   **ProblemType**
>        Crash
>   **Title**
>        Xorg crashed with SIGABRT in OsAbort()

I went through steps of UPDATE APRIL:
    there were no **~/.config/upstart/lowgfx.conf** file,
    I deleted files of **~/.cache/** library (and left its sublibraries),
    there were no **/var/crash/** files,
    I have added the terminal command **sed -i 's/-lowgfx//' ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config**,
    restarted the system with ubuntu menu.

There were no changes in the behaviour of the system
    (1)the restart stopped with ubuntu on the middle of the screen with 5 dots running below it, and press of Esc resulted black screen
    (2)upstart (or recovery + resume) works
    (3)no revoke from sleep

What to do?

Comment: It belongs to problem"GUI/Unity crashing in 16.04 LTS after updates 2018-01-04, compiz segfaults"

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared to the end of October. A possible reason: something was (is?) not initialised in its correct place, but this causes error in some circumstances only. As a consequence of next updates the circumstances have changed. I am afraid, the problem may return, but now doesn't exist.